# Array.IndexOf: Equals & CompareTo

Tags: c#, .net

In this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat.aspx), it says that

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, this method uses the  **Equals and  CompareTo methods of the  Array** to determine whether the  Object specified by the value parameter exists. In the *earlier* versions of the .NET Framework, this determination was made by using the  Equals and  CompareTo methods of the value  *Object* itself.

What exactly does this mean?  From what I can tell using Reflector, Array.IndexOf still uses the equals method of the object to determine the index of the object in the array:

```
for (int j = startIndex; j < num3; j++)
{
    object obj2 = objArray[j];
    if ((obj2 != null) && obj2.Equals(value))
    {
        return j;
    }
}
```

This *is* what I expected, but I'm a little confused by the **MSDN Remark**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (very) poorly worded, but it means that in 1.1, it searched for an `arrayElement` with

```
value.Equals(arrayElement) == true
```

while in 2.0 it searches for one with

```
arrayElement.Equals(value) == true
```

That is, the equivalent piece of reflected code from 1.1 was

```
for (int j = startIndex; j < num3; j++)
{
    object obj2 = objArray[j];
    if ((obj2 != null) && value.Equals(obj2))
    {
        return j;
    }
}
```