# Which .Equals() method to use

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346549/array-indexof-equals-compareto/1346597). we discovered that in .NET 1.1, `Array.IndexOf(array, value)` searched for an element with

```
value.Equals(arrayElement) == true
```

while .NET 2.0 changed it to search for an element with

```
arrayElement.Equals(value) == true
```

Obviously the potential difference between the two results arises from polymorphism, but is there any reason why the latter version is preferable? More generally, if I have two objects `a` and `b` to compare, is there any good reason to prefer `a.Equals(b)` or `b.Equals(a)`?

Comment: While I agree with you @recursive, in this context it emphasizes the point of the code snippet.

Comment: I wouldn't write `if ( value.Equals(arrayElement) == true )`, but as Austin says, the emphasis seemed useful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is done to avoid problems when you override `Equals` in object you're feeding into `IndexOf`. In other words, if you have `class Foo` with some weird `Equals` implementation, this:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
Bar b = arrayOfDateTimes.IndexOf(f);
```

could potentially disrupt the behavior and yield strange results.

Comment: But isn't it just as likely that you've got a weird `Equals` override on the object stored in the array? They seem to be equally risky, but since it's potentially a breaking change it feels like MS should have had a reason to bother changing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but the 1.1 version may have had a higher rate of NullReferenceExceptions compared to the 2.0 version.